# Mongoose - find child by Id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, handlebars.js

Details: Here is my schema layout

```
Schema Layout:
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

module.exports = function(db) {

let gameSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

opponent: String,
location: String,
date: String,
completions: Number,
attempts: Number,
yards: Number,
touchdowns: Number,
interceptions: Number,
});

let quarterbackSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
firstName: String, 
lastName: String,
school: String,
age: Number,
hometown: String,
games:[gameSchema]
});
```

Here is what a stored document looks like

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "5c0a551df8555c1c1ef0c101"
},
"firstName": "Pepper",
"lastName": "Princess ",
"age": 14,
"hometown": "Farmville, Ms",
"school": "Farmers School of Important Stuff",
"games": [
    {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "5c0ca5ba7213fe6a5f52848c"
        },
        "opponent": "Crock McSnagglebite",
        "location": "Pattys Putrid Flower Garden",
        "date": "1/23/2020",
        "completions": 777,
        "attempts": 777,
        "yards": 777,
        "touchdowns": 777,
        "interceptions": 777
    }
],
"__v": 1
}
```

Question: 
I'm trying to find the subdocument by its _id. The example code I have posted displays the number as "5c0ca5ba7213fe6a5f52848c".

I have tried

```
 Quarterback.find({_id: req.body.id}).then(function(Results){});

 Quarterback.findOne({_id: req.body.id}).then(ect...

 Quarterback.findById({_id: req.body.id}).then(ect...
```

and many, many other ways, I simply don't know what I'm doing wrong. I used

JSON.stringify(req.body)); to verify the route was returning my desired value and it is
**my console.log outputs the following**

This is game details req.body:: {"child":"5c0d02649c936072d47f12a9"}

but find keeps returning null for a result, when using the above methods. I'm a student and still learning, so maybe I'm missing something easy. I'm hoping someone here can help. Thank you so much for your time!!

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your quarterback schema.
`games:[gameSchema]` should be

`games:[game:{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref: 'games'}]`
After correcting this, you should be able to run this query:
`Quarterback.find({games: req.body.id}).then(function(Results){});`

Comment: @Michael Murphy is this helpful?

Answer (score 0):

You may try

```
const quarterback =  Quarterback.find({_id: req.body.quaterbackId})
const game = quarterback.games.id(req.body.gameId)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
Quarterback.find({games._id: req.body.id}).then(function(Results){});
```

should work. You have to pass game._id because that's how JSON objects and properties are accessed

Comment: When I try Quarterback.find({games._id: req.body.id}).then(function(Results){}); I get the error  "syntaxError: Unexpected token . " for the "." between games and _id. Thank you so much for helping me.